# How to get list of git branches in Rails application?

Tags: git, git-branch

Can I get list of branches in Rails app somehow? I need access to branches list of particular git repository(not repository of my app) in my app. So maybe some gem for this exists ?

Comment: if an answer helps you, it's always good to up-vote. Also mark the correct answer

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is just to use the git branch commands’ various options. -a shows all local and remote branches, while -r shows only remote branches.

```
$ git branch
* master

$ git branch -a
* master
 origin/1-2-stable
 origin/2-0-stable
 origin/2-1-stable
 origin/2-2-stable
 origin/3-0-unstable
 origin/HEAD
 origin/master

$ git branch -r
 origin/1-2-stable
 origin/2-0-stable
 origin/2-1-stable
 origin/2-2-stable
 origin/3-0-unstable
 origin/HEAD
 origin/master
```

Answer (score 2):

**git branch --all** and **git branch -a** both are same this command will display all branches.

```
$ git branch --all
asset_pipeline_changes
live
* master
secondary_menu
remotes/origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

```
**git branch -a**
```

displays all local and remote branches, while

```
**git branch -r**
```

will display only the remote branches.